# Foundation 6 reveal open on page load with cookies not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, zurb-foundation

I am trying to create a modal reveal which opens on page load with zurb foundation 6. I would also like for the browser to store a cookie so that if the user closes the reveal it will not bother them for another 7 days.

I am using a jquery plugin for cookies found [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Here is my html:

```
<div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
  <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
  <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
  <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
  <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

As you can see i do not have a data-open element because i would like the modal to open once the page loads.

here is my jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 if ($.cookie('modal_shown') === null) {
        $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
        $("#exampleModal1").foundation('reveal', 'open');
    }
});
```

The jquery is in no conflict mode.

This however does not seem to be working. I do not get any errors through my developer console in chrome. I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the solution incase anyone else needs it.

Turns out that in foundation 6, you do not need to use both reveal and open method, just open.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if($.cookie('showed_modal') != "true") {
    $("#exampleModal1").foundation("open");
    $.cookie('showed_modal', 'true', { expires: 7, path: '/'}); 
  }
});
```